# How can I know if a variable can be written directly into a binary file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, c++14

I've written this function:

```
template <typename T>
ofstream bfwrite(ofstream &os, const T &data) {
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), sizeof(data));
    return os;
}
```

I know this won't work for some types because, for example, they point to data on the heap.
So I want to do a compile time check, but I couldn't find suited functions in the reference.

There are three options: `is_trivially_copyable`, `is_pod` or just using serialization libraries of other people. Everything you can do when learning a language is done already by somebody else, so I'd stick to one of the first two options.
`is_trivially_copyable` is safe enough for me. See the accepted answer for more detail.

Comment: For an arbitrary class this can not be done.

Comment: So the language doesn't support this? Then I'll have to write overloads for each stl class and the user has to continue for his own classes. )-:

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel? There's [boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for the STL...and users writing serialization for their own data types is standard practice.

Comment: I've not looked at boost yet. Is it hard to install and so on?

Comment: @Timon Why do you need to know? Do you plan applying _a design flaw_?

Comment: @TheDude Do you mean the main or the comment question?

Comment: @TimonPaßlick Stackoverflow is not a forum. Do not add 'solved' and such to your title. Read the [faq]. Get to know the site before using it.

Comment: @Timon I mainly meant the `reinterpret_cast<char*>(data)`. That's probably the worst choice unless you're a 100% sure dealing with POD types. Don't do that!

Comment: @dandan78 I'm sorry, I'll read it.

Comment: @TheDude So it's not enough to know it's trivially copyable? Ok, I'll change the enable_if condition to is_pod.

Comment: @Timon Read up about _de-/serialization_. There's a number of non-standard techniques that would work successfully like `boost::arcive` or google protocol buffers.

Comment: @TheDude Yes, I know, but I want to write my own solution to get practice.

Comment: Bad Idea and full of pitfalls to manage in 1st place.

Comment: @TheDude So what would you recommend instead?

Comment: See my comment above, I already recommended what to use instead.

Comment: No, you seem to be an expert. What should I do instead to improve my skills?

Comment: Oh, my question above was primarily opinion based. Finished reading the tour. ( ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable trait.

> Objects of trivially-copyable types are the only C++ objects that may
>   be safely copied with std::memcpy or serialized to/from binary files
>   with std::ofstream::write()/std::ifstream::read().

Specifically, my emphasis:

> In general, a
>   trivially copyable type is any type for which the underlying bytes can
>   be **copied to an array of char** or unsigned char and into a new object
>   of the same type, and the resulting object would have the same value
>   as the original.

```
template <typename T>
ofstream bfwrite(ofstream &os, const T &data)
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "T must be trivially copyable");
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), sizeof(data));

    return os;
}
```

or, if you need [sfine](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), something like this:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,
  ofstream>::type bfwrite(ofstream &os, const T &data)
{
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), sizeof(data));

    return os;
}
```

Comment: I already had a look at that, it's close, but unfortunately, it's not exactly enough what I want. Anyways, thank you for answering.

Comment: Hmm - how come? what types that are not trivially copyable do you hope to stream like this?

Comment: I thought it wouldn't work for 2d data structures but I was wrong. I tested it again and now, it works. There was an error in my first test.

Comment: [FWIW](https://ideone.com/y2BmcO). You can save these objects to files. It is just not guaranteed you can retrieve them the way you want.

Comment: As long as you save the bits correctly and use the same version of compiler, platform etc its guaranteed. You may need to use memcpy to deserialize, into 'alligned storrage' or more naturally to an existing instanve of T.